# Can someone explain me the code written for sms32v50 assembly

Tags: assembly, seven-segment-display

Hello i have exercise to do a clock which will be counting from 1 to 59 in loop without ending. Can someone answer me to couple questions ?

1. Why there are such numbers after DB? Is it ASCII or what?
2. Why to BL we adding 03 ?

If someone can explain me line after line code.
Thanks do much.

Language: sms32v50 assembler

```
    JMP start
    DB FA ; 0
    DB 0A ; 1
    DB B6 ; 2
    DB 9E ; 3
    DB 4E ; 4
    DB DC ; 5
    DB FC ; 6
    DB 8A ; 7
    DB FE ; 8
    DB DE ; 9
start:
    MOV DL, 00 
start1:
    MOV [90], DL
    MOV BL, [90]
    MOD BL, 0A
    ADD BL, 03
    MOV AL, [BL]
    INC AL
    OUT 02
    MOV BL, [90]
    DIV BL, 0A
    ADD BL, 03
    MOV AL, [BL]
    OUT 02
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    INC DL
    CMP DL, 3C
    JNZ koniec
    MOV DL, 00
    JMP start1
koniec:
    JMP start1
    END
```

I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: The hex values with the `DB`s look like 7-segment LED encodings

Answer (score 2):

All the numbers in your code are expressed as hexadecimal. Normally this would require either a "0x" prefix or an "h" suffix.
eg. `CMP DL, 3C` would have to be written as `CMP DL, 0x3C` or `CMP DL, 3Ch`.

The code has numerous errors based on the [x86-16](/questions/tagged/x86-16) tag:

- `MOD BL, 0A` There's no such `mod` instruction for x86-16.
- `MOV AL, [BL]` You can't use a byte register for addressing memory.
- `OUT 02` Outputting needs to specify the size.
- `DIV BL, 0A` No dividing by an immediate available.

> Why there are such numbers after `DB`? Is it ASCII or what?

No ASCII, I am pretty sure these numbers are bitvectors that would enable to visualize the decimal digits as if on a digital clock (with 7 segments).
The bits correspond to the segments as follows:

```
  <--7-->
 |       |
|6|     |1|
 |       |
  <--2-->
 |       |
|5|     |3|
 |       |
  <--4-->
```

> Why to BL we adding 03 ?

Who knows in a code with this many errors, but again I am almost sure the 03 is a typo for 30 which would add 48 in decimal to convert from [0,9] into ["0","9"].

### EDIT: It's code for a sms32v50 simulator

The above mentioned errors become void!
After having read the help page provided by Michael Petch, I now better understand where that 'adding 03' comes from: it's the address in memory where the table with the bitvectors is stored.
Code like

```
ADD BL, 03
MOV AL, [BL]
```

is equivalent to

```
MOV AL, [3 + BL]
```

The `INC AL` is added to the bitvector so as to output to the rightmost digit. Without setting bit 0, output goes to the leftmost digit.

`ADD BL, 03` could still be an error knowing that `JMP start` has but a 2-byte encoding! We would have to see the program in action to know for sure. It could relate to the task description ("a clock which will be counting from **1** to 59") because the program currently starts from **0** in the DL register...

Comment: This is correct code because my lecturer sent it. In our compilator this code works. Thanks for helping.

Comment: We are coding in simulator and i guess there are some simplifications.

Comment: Yeah this is for a sms32v50 simulator which is basically a processor that is effectively 8 bits. It has some additional instructions and the addressing modes are 8 bit. They do have a `mod` instruction as well. https://ininet.org/microprocessor-simulator-0-help-v2.html?page=82